# MVC 5 Grid.MVC Post whole grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some problem with POST Grid.MVC content. My model is send to grid as IQueryable type:

```
 @using GridMvc.Html
@model IQueryable<ViewModels.AdministratorDashboard.AuctionViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Auctions";
    Layout = "_AdministratorDashboard.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Grid(Model, new GridRenderOptions {Selectable = false}).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(d => d.Id)
            .Titled("Id")
            .Sortable(true);

        columns.Add(d => d.Title)
            .Titled("Title")
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(true)
            .Sanitized(false)
            .Encoded(false)
            .RenderValueAs(d => Html.ActionLink(d.Title, "Auction", "Auctions", new {@id = d.Id}, null));


        columns.Add(d => d.IsVisible)
            .Titled("Visible")
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(true)
            .Encoded(false)
            .Sanitized(false)
            .RenderValueAs(d => Html.CheckBox("Visible", d.IsVisible, null));

        columns.Add(d => d.ItemAvailable)
            .Titled("Item available")
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(true)
            .Encoded(false)
            .Sanitized(false)
            .RenderValueAs(d => Html.CheckBox("Item avaiable", d.ItemAvailable, null));

    })

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

What I want after post is get whole posted data in grid and update some data (check boxes values). But when I post it to controller I got null in model:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAllAuctions(ICollection<AuctionViewModel> model)
    {
        //model is null...

        return View();
    }
```

I try IQueryable, IEnumerable etc. it not help me. Maybe someone have similar problem and know how to solve it.

Comment: Try using fiddler and see what the names are getting posted to the Action. For example, I once had data being sent such as `myModel.Id, myModel.Name` from the VIEW and the controller was along the lines of `ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)`. I had to change it to `MyModel myModel` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I checked what is send to controller and it seams something wrong is generated: {Id=1017&Id=1018&Id=1019&Id=1020&Id=1021&IsVisible=true&IsVisible=false&IsVisible=true&IsVisible=false&IsVisible=false&IsVisible=false&IsVisible=false&ItemAvailable=false&ItemAvailable=false&ItemAvailable=true&ItemAvailable=false&ItemAvailable=true&ItemAvailable=false&ItemAvailable=true&ItemAvailable=false}